# Buttons stop working

Tags: android, button, android-mediaplayer

I have several buttons. Each one plays a different sound when pressed.
After using the app for 2 or 3 minutes, the buttons stop playing any sound.
I'll simplify the code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/but"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button b;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MainActivity t=this;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int q=v.getId();
        if(q==R.id.but)
        {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(t,R.raw.song);
            mp.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting. Post the logs

Comment: Does the song finishes playing after 2-3 minutes and you cannot start it again, or does the button just stop handling clicks for no reason?

Comment: The audio is max 10 seconds long. It stops handling clicks for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are done playing, it's recommended to call `release()` on your `MediaPlayer` object.

As stated in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29)

> ... failure to call release() may cause subsequent instances of
>   MediaPlayer objects to fallback to software implementations or fail
>   altogether.

Additionally, you should have a look on the [MediaPlayer states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to ask silly questions or to bother anyone, but the tutorial I read about Media Player said nothing about the release() method
I'd upvote you, but I got a minus at this question and I've got only 14 reputation points elft

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer was helpful to you, please tick it as accepted :-) Happy coding! @IulianDutu

Comment: I somehow gained reputation ;)